# Finding unique sub-lists in nested lists

Tags: python, unique, nested-lists

for quite some time now I've been struggling with the following problem:

Consider the following example nested list: `example_nestedlist = [['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry']]`

This is one of the many nested lists that I generate from my product data, and for each of these nested lists (containing 1-100 lists) I want to re-create the nested list, such that it contains **only unique sub-lists**.

The expected output may be as follows:
`output_nestedlist = [['Apple'], ['Orange'], ['Banana'], ['Strawberry'], ['Apple', 'Banana']]`.

The expected output is not limited to this though. For example, the second sub-list could be `['Apple', 'Orange']` as well, instead of only `['Orange']`.
The ultimate goal remains to have unique sub-lists, irrespective of what is actually in those sub-lists (or what length they are).

I've already been exploring several approaches, for example:

- Using `set()` to generate as many 'different' unique sub-lists.
- While also using `set()` to detect completely similar sub-lists, in which case I used randomization to select the item(s) to appear in the sublist.
- both of these approaches were followed by an abundance of 'rules' I created to catch exceptions.

However, this resulted (and is still resulting in) a pretty unscalable approach, as it is now to much fixated in what is inside the nested list, not the problem itself.
Perhaps I am missing out on something, and just need some *rubber ducking* over here..

But I hope someone can give me a direction to look into, all help is much appreciated!

*edit1*: It is also essential that the order of the sublists is preserved, as these need to be connected to their unique identifier later on.

Comment: Its unclear what is unique about the sublists. They don't contain the same items? If so, isn't it just `set(tuple(subl) for subl in sublists)` ?

Comment: Ideally you show one input set and **all** valid results if there are multiple soutions. 
This will ensure we really understand your requirements

Comment: @ReutSharabani Ah sorry, my bad! The uniqueness means that there is no one sublist that is exactly the same as another sublist, in both length and items in it. They may all contain similar items, as long as there is always a difference between every sublist.

Comment: @gelonida You're right, but I hoped 'all possible combinations' would be okay. It doesn't matter whatever is in each sub-list, as long as all sub-lists are unique (meaning no two sublists with exactly the same items in it). I tried to denote it here as a 'simple' example, however in my actual working dataset, there are nested lists that contain sublists in which each of these sublists have around 10-25 items.

Comment: @ReutSharabani Unfortunately that solution does not work, mainly because of the reason it ignores the order of the sublists within the nested list. Should add that to requirements :)

Comment: To keep the order just store the result of the operation I posted and filter any list that didn't make it. Checking membership in a set is fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NOTE: Deleted last answer as it wasn't matching the requirement.

It looks like you need to use combinations.
Result matches conditions:

1. Result list should be as same length as input list
2. Each item in `result` should be subset of corresponding item in `input` list
3. Result list should not have duplicate sublists.

```
from itertools import combinations

example_nestedlist = [['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Apple', 'Orange'], ['Apple', 'Banana'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry'], ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Strawberry']]

result = []

def fill_load(sublist):
    for i in range(1, len(sublist) + 1):
        for combo in combinations(sublist, i):
            item = list(combo)
            if item not in result:
                result.append(item)
                return
    result.append(None)

for sublist in example_nestedlist:
    fill_load(sublist)

print(result)
```

Output:

```
[['Apple'], ['Orange'], ['Banana'], ['Strawberry'], ['Apple', 'Banana']]
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, I need to retain every single sublist in the `example_nestedlist`. See them as 5 'food trucks', they all carry several fruits (input), which could be complete duplicate, but when I finally 'open' each truck, I want to see a different combination of fruits in each truck. Thus truck 1 could have `['Apple']`, truck 2 `['Apple', 'Orange']`. But truck 1 could also have `['Orange']` and truck 2 `['Apple']`. But also truck 1 could have `['Apple', 'Orange']` and truck 2 could have either `['Apple']` or `['Orange']`.

Comment: It simply doesn't matter whatever combination of fruits each truck is carrying, as long as each truck has a unique 'load'. But key is that all 5 trucks (in this example) need to carry one or more fruits.

Comment: So based in input list, can truck 1 carry `['Banana']` or it has to be either `['Apple']`or `['Orange']` or `['Apple', 'Orange']`

Comment: The latter, the sublists are 'fixed', in terms of possible items. So items cannot be swapped between sublists :)

Comment: Updated the answer, let me know if it still doesn't match to any of your requirement

Comment: Incredible, one hell of a Eureka moment right now! This works like a charm, and it's very fast! You made my day :)